# Best time to close channel, when iterating over channel

Tags: go

I am playing around with Golang and I created this little app to make several concurrent api calls using goroutines.

While the app works, after the calls complete, the app gets stuck, which makes sense because it cannot exit the **range c** loop because the channel is not closed.

I am not sure where to better close the channel in this pattern.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"

func main() {
    links := []string{
        "https://github.com/fabpot",
        "https://github.com/andrew",
        "https://github.com/taylorotwell",
        "https://github.com/egoist",
        "https://github.com/HugoGiraudel",
    }

    checkUrls(links)
}

func checkUrls(urls []string) {
    c := make(chan string)

    for _, link := range urls {
        go checkUrl(link, c)
    }

    for msg := range c {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }

    close(c) //this won't get hit
}

func checkUrl(url string, c chan string) {
    _, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        c <- "We could not reach:" + url
    } else {
        c <- "Success reaching the website:" + url
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You close a channel when there are no more values to send, so in this case it's when all `checkUrl` goroutines have completed.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func checkUrls(urls []string) {
    c := make(chan string)

    for _, link := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go checkUrl(link, c)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()

    for msg := range c {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}

func checkUrl(url string, c chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    _, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        c <- "We could not reach:" + url
    } else {
        c <- "Success reaching the website:" + url
    }
}
```

(Note that the `error` from `http.Get` is only going to reflect connection and protocol errors. It is not going to contain http server errors if you're expecting those too, which you must be seeing how you're checking for paths and not just hosts.)

Comment: Slick solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When writing programs in Go using channels and goroutines always think about who (which function) owns a channel. I prefer the practice of letting the function who owns a channel close it. If i were to write this i would do as shown below.

Note: A better way to handle situations like this is the **Fan-out, fan-in** concurrency pattern. refer(https://blog.golang.org/pipelines)[Go Concurrency Patterns](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines)

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"
import "sync"

func main() {
    links := []string{
        "https://github.com/fabpot",
        "https://github.com/andrew",
        "https://github.com/taylorotwell",
        "https://github.com/egoist",
        "https://github.com/HugoGiraudel",
    }


    processURLS(links)
    fmt.Println("End of Main")
}

func processURLS(links []string) {
    resultsChan := checkUrls(links)

    for msg := range resultsChan {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }

}     

func checkUrls(urls []string) chan string {

    outChan := make(chan string)

    go func(urls []string) {
       defer close(outChan)

       var wg sync.WaitGroup
       for _, url := range urls {
         wg.Add(1)
          go checkUrl(&wg, url, outChan)
       }
       wg.Wait()

    }(urls)

    return outChan
}

func checkUrl(wg *sync.WaitGroup, url string, c chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    _, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        c <- "We could not reach:" + url
    } else {
        c <- "Success reaching the website:" + url
    }
}
```